# (google map android) add multiple markers on top of of a geojson layer

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, geojson

I am trying to markers on top of the highlight the geojson layer above but I cannot add more than one marker. I have played with the zIndex but it does not seem to work
here is my add marker and geojson code:

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            try {
                Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(ScratchmapActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addrs = null;
                addrs = gc.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 2);
                String country =addrs.get(0).getCountryName();
                zInd++;
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(
                    "aloha").zIndex(zInd));

            }catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


public void addGeoJsonLayer(int color, int resource){

    try {
        GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, resource, getApplicationContext());

        GeoJsonPolygonStyle style = layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
        style.setFillColor(color);
        style.setStrokeColor(color);
        style.setStrokeWidth(1F);
        style.setZIndex((float) 1);

        layer.addLayerToMap();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("IOException", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        Log.e("JSONException", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PJdp.png)

Answer (score 0):

it seems late for answering this question but I've encountered same problem and I passed this issue by using a closed linestring instead of polygon.

```
    val listPoints = mutableListOf<LatLng>() 
    listPoints.addAll(vertices)
    listPoints.add(vertices.first())
    val gsLineString = GeoJsonLineString(listPoints)
```